# UISplitViewController Detail View Drop shadow

Tags: ios6, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to set a shadow on my UISplitViewController's Detail View, that I want to be visible over the Master View, in iOS 6.

In my Detail ViewController:

```
 self.view.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
 self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-3.0f, 0.0f);
 self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
 self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
 self.view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
 self.view.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

However, the SplitVC automatically clips its sub-views, even when I set it to NO in the above code, and there is no shadow.

Can anyone let me know the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you in portrait or landscape orientation ?

Comment: @tdubik I'm in landscape. I want the shadow to fall on the extreme right of the master view, so that it looks like the detail view is slightly overlapping the master.

Comment: I had a similar case, but what was clipping isn't the UISplitViewController, but the UINavigationController that was the in the detail view. The shadow was fine after I `navigationController.view.clipsToBounds = false`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to do this is to add a 1px view to the master view controller and snap it to the right edge and apply a shadow to that view instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a superview some way down the hierarchy is performing the clipping.

Try this:

```
UIView *v = self.view;
do
{
    v.clipsToBounds = NO;
    v = v.superview;
}
while(v != nil);
```

Be aware that this will turn of clipping for all view in the hierarchy! - This might be more than you asked for:-).